# Docker Volume is not working for deployments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am following lynda Docker tutorials and performing stuff related to docker compose file.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
more docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: jboss/wildfly
    volumes:
      - ~/deployments:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

As per authors, I am trying to copy `webapp.war` file to `deployments/` folder giving me error. ***It look like volume mapping for the docker file is not working.***

> cp /home/user/Demos/docker-for-java/chapter2/webapp.war deployments/
>   cp: cannot create regular file ‘deployments/’: Not a directory

```
docker-compose ps
     Name                   Command               State           Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
helloweb_web_1   /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/sta ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be misinterpreting tutorial. I haven't seen the tutorial itself, but checking the documentation for the WildFly Docker image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/) there's a mention that you need to extend base image and add your `war` file inside:

> To do this you just need to extend the jboss/wildfly image by creating a new one. Place your application inside the deployments/ directory with the ADD command (but make sure to include the trailing slash on the deployment folder path, more info). You can also do the changes to the configuration (if any) as additional steps (RUN command).

This means that you need to create a `Dockerfile` with approximately this contents (change `your-awesome-app.war` with the path to your `war` file):

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD your-awesome-app.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

After that you need to change you `docker-compose.yml` to build from your `Dockerfile` instead of using `jboss/wildfly` (note the use of `build: .` instead of `image: jboss/wildfly`):

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Try that and comment if you run into any issues

Comment: Thnx for suggestion. No, I'ven't  misinterpreted the tutorial, followed exactly the same steps. Because docker-compose.yml file having the enrty for the volume mapping and when I execute the `docker-compose up -d` network drive should have mounted and I should be able to copy .war file to /deployments folder